# Programmatically setting d3 zoom transform

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have both an image and a linear scale that I need to zoom in/out.

I have done this by getting the Y domain of the zoom transform and successfully zooming both that way:

`y.domain(zoomTransform.rescaleY(y).domain());`

But is it possible to do the reverse? Set the zoomTransform.k and zoomTransform.y values based on the Y domain of the scale? And in that way allowing the user to specifically setting the zoom-domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating loops to gently modify the `zoomTransform.y` and `k` values and then fetching `y.invert(0)` and `y.invert(height)` values to check if the result was closer to the wanted range on every iteration. Had to put a another loop on top of these as changing the y affects the k and changing the k affects the y...

Not very pretty but seems to do the job.